# vm.runInContext: Why can't this function access a global object that should be in the context?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eval

Using Node v10.13.0, I don't understand why this code errors out instead of printing "Bill":

```
const vm = require('vm');

function printName() {
    console.log(defaultName);
}

const sandbox = { defaultName: 'Bill', printName: printName };
vm.createContext(sandbox);
vm.runInContext('printName()', sandbox);
```

When I run it, I get this:

```
$ node ./eval-js.js 
/Users/wiseman/src/typescript-eval-test/eval-js.js:4
    console.log(defaultName);
                ^

ReferenceError: defaultName is not defined
    at printName (/Users/wiseman/src/typescript-eval-test/eval-js.js:4:17)
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:1
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:107:20)
    at Object.runInContext (vm.js:285:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/wiseman/src/typescript-eval-test/eval-js.js:9:4)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
```

Comment: Because you've passed a closure, which closes over a non-existing variable. If you had declared the function in the code that's running inside the sandbox, it would have been able to access the global variables of the sandbox.